# A Database Error Occurred 1452

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I am working on a project that requires me to use foreign keys in phpMyAdmin. I set the foreign key on two tables. `tblquestions` is linked to `answers` table but when i try to insert data into `tblquestions` I get this error

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1452
>
> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`user_test`.`tblquestions`, CONSTRAINT `tblquestions_ibfk_5` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`QID`) REFERENCES `answers` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE
>   CASCADE)
>
> INSERT INTO `tblquestions` (`Question`, `qA`, `qB`, `qC`) VALUES
>   ('unikalus klausimas', 'unikalus atsakymas', 'unikalus atsakymas',
>   'unikalus atsakymas')

Comment: whats the difference between tables with joins and tables with foreign key ?

Comment: do u know any tutorials maby that can help me setting up a tables with joins ?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar - Foreign keys help to enforce referential integrity. Please don't suggest others to avoid using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foreign key is basically nothing more than the rule "an entry in a table must have a corresponding value in the referenced table".

In your case the logic would be, that there can not be answers to nonexisting questions. So you put up the foreign key the wrong way.

Then, when you insert data you have to insert the rows for the questions first. When you insert the rows for the answers, you have to lookup the ID of the question the answer belongs to.

And btw, ignore Yogesh Suthar's comments, please. Foreign keys are a really important feature of databases to ensure data integrity, and obviously he has no clue what he's talking about.

Answer (score 0):

If you have linked `tblquestions` to `answers` you should first add an answer(s) and then the question. Otherwise the referential integrity cannot be maintained since the you are trying to add a child before parent. (Always add parent before child.)

Heres one way to do it. Lets use two tables: `tbl_question`, `tbl_answer`.

`tbl_question` has at least two columns:

- id: `int`
- question: `text`

`tbl_answer` contains answer which may be correct (or wrong if you liked to add a set of optional answers to one question).

- question_id: `int`, FK to `tbl_question` `id`
- answer_option: `tinyint(1)`/`char(1)`, a set of optional answers to a single question
- answer: `text`
- is_correct: `tinyint(1)`/`byte(1)` (marks the correct answer to question)

Make the `question_id` and `answer_option` a composite PK. Now you can join the two tables by their `id`/`question_id` and get all the optional answers to a single question. Just make sure only one of them is marked as correct.

---

I'll post this answer although you have already accepted an answer while I've been writing this. Like tombom said, you have a FK established the wrong way.

Not sure what you mean by asking tutorials on setting up tables with joins. You should first be familiar with the concept of foreign key and then you can join your tables any way you like. Here are few links.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key
- http://www.sitepoint.com/mysql-foreign-keys-quicker-database-development/
- [What is the difference between Left, Right, Outer and Inner Joins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448023/what-is-the-difference-between-left-right-outer-and-inner-joins)
- http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

A concept of FK is quite simply a column which is related to a column on another table (you join the two or more tables by using the values of the foreign key columns). Just remember to add a FK constraint between those tables/values so you RDBMS warns you when you are trying to do something that breaks the constraint. Like here when you were trying to add an answer to a nonexistent question.

And finally, use InnoDB if you are concerned about referential integrity (as every DB designer/manager/admin should be).

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html